# Using WWAN and WiFi simultaneously

Tags: wireless-networking, wwan

I have a Windows 10 Tablet that has a WWAN 4G Modem and a WiFi adapter. The WiFi adapter is used to talk to another local computer (not connected to the internet), and the 4G Modem is used to talk to the internet. Independently, they work great. However, when they are both turned on at the same time and connected to their respective network/device, only one of them has a priority over the other at any given time that I cannot seem to find a way to control. So either the WWAN works and I can access the internet but am not able to talk to the other computer over WiFi (ping/ftp), or when the WiFi has the priority I can ping/ftp into the local computer, but am not able to access the internet with the WWAN. I tried turning off Automatic Metric from the Network Adapter Settings and set the Interface Metric with a higher number for one adapter and a lower for another, and then switched them, but it seems that the WWAN has the priority both times.

Note: I disconnected from the WiFi Network and used an Ethernet cable to connect this tablet to the local computer just as a test, and everything was working fine (without any changes to the Interface Metrics).

Answer (score 2):

Add a route for the local LAN that specifies the WiFi as the interface for that traffic.

From `route add /?`:

```
> route ADD 157.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0  157.55.80.1 METRIC 3 IF 2
         destination^      ^mask      ^gateway     metric^    ^
                                                     Interface^
  If IF is not given, it tries to find the best interface for a given
  gateway.
```

Comment: I tried that and it still lets me access the local computer, but I'm still not able to access the internet. I also tried to remove the default route of the WiFi interface by issuing "route delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 X.X.X.X if INTERFACE" It no longer appears in "netstat -rn" however I still don't have any luck with getting onto the internet through 4G.